# How to pass multiple named parameters to Spring JdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, database, spring, jdbc

I have following code in a Spring Dao which works just fine -

```
Object args[] = { userId, restaurantId };
int userOrderCount = getJdbcTemplate()
    .queryForInt(
         "SELECT COUNT(orderid) FROM orders WHERE useridfk_order = ? AND restaurantidfk_order = ?", 
         args
    );
```

However if I decide to use NamedParameters for my query as follows -

```
int userOrderCount = getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate()
    .queryForInt(
         "SELECT COUNT(orderid) FROM orders WHERE useridfk_order = :userId AND restaurantidfk_order = :restaurantId", 
         new MapSqlParameterSource(":restaurantId", restaurantId)
             .addValue(":userId", userId)
    );
```

I am getting this exception -

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'userId': No value registered for key 'userId'.
```

I know the golden adage "Don't fix it if it ain't broken".

But still, I can't help but wonder why this is happening?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use this.

```
new MapSqlParameterSource("restaurantId", restaurantId)
    .addValue("userId", userId);
```

instead of this.

```
new MapSqlParameterSource(":restaurantId", restaurantId)
    .addValue(":userId", userId);
```

Comment: (+1) correct: to make it more clear for the reader: you must not have that `:` in front of the map parameter